# Do I need to build a downloaded package?

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear community, I'm unsure how to use a third-party package I downloaded online from Github: https://github.com/osrf/car_demo

Inside this folder, the `car_demo` folder has the structure of a ROS package. After downloading it, how do I let me local version of ROS know the existence of this package? e.g. use `roscd` to this particular package. Do I need to run `catkin_build` somewhere?

Thanks!

Edit!!!

I realized this folder is not a ROS package since it does not have `src` and `build`and `devel` space. But still, if it has, do I need to run `catkin_build` again?

Edit again!!!

For this particular package (?), the author published it in a docker environment with something called racker that I couldn't get running on my laptop, because racker only works with Python 3 and all my ROS stuff are in Python 2. That's why the README in this project does not work for me and I am trying to build things locally "in my own way".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324287/do-i-need-to-build-a-downloaded-package?/) by [Sparkle Eyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/38320/sparkle-eyes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2019-05-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Dear community, I'm unsure how to use a third-party package I downloaded online from Github: https://github.com/osrf/car_demo

> Inside this folder, the `car_demo` folder has the structure of a ROS package. After downloading it, how do I let me local version of ROS know the existence of this package? e.g. use `roscd` to this particular package.

If you `git clone` a ROS package (or multiple packages) from an online repository then you must build that in a Catkin workspace, yes.

A large number of ROS packages will be written in a language that needs to be compiled (such as C++) before you can use the resulting nodes (ie: binaries), so without compiling, you only have a set of source files and headers. Not something you could `rosrun` or `roslaunch`.

> Do I need to run `catkin_build` somewhere?

As part of the process of building a Catkin workspace, you'd run `catkin_make`, indeed (not `catkin_build`).

Or, if you'd like, you could install `catkin_tools` and run `catkin build` (note: no underscore).

> I realized this folder is not a ROS package since it does not have `src` and `build`and `devel` space.

ROS *packages* do not have `build` and `devel` folders, only Catkin *workspaces* do.

In fact: if you ever see a repository that does contain `build` and `devel` folders, the author has essentially made a mistake, as those folders should never be added to a VCS.

---

As to the process of building packages that you downloaded the sources for from some online repository: please refer to the answer of #q252478 for an example workflow.

In general it is not sufficient to simply copy the sources in a Catkin workspace and then running `catkin_make` (or `catkin build`), as your system wouldn't have the necessary dependencies installed. Without those dependencies the build will fail.

Provided the author of the package you intend to build has done a proper job and has listed all build and run dependencies correctly in his package manifest (ie: `package.xml`), the workflow shown in #q252478 should install them all for you.

With the dependencies installed, running `catkin_make` (or `catkin build`) is the last step then.

---

Edit: and finally: please always consider whether you need to build a package from source. In many cases packages have been released through the ROS buildfarm, which means that a simple `sudo apt install ros-<rosdistro>-package-name` will install everything for you.

Using binaries is always preferable over building things from sources, unless you know what you are doing or have a specific need.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sparkle Eyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/38320/sparkle-eyes/) on 2019-05-30**:
Wow, thanks so much for the detailed answer! I actually tried the whole `catkin build` process myself yesterday, but had to initialize a new workspace first, create packages there, and then copy the `CMakeLists.ext` and the `packages.xml` files from the cloned folder into that new clean workspace, so I know I have the correct structure. But your explanations on the whole workflow helps a lot!!! Also the `catkin_make` and `catkin build` tools --- I understand them as two tools but am not familiar enough to tell them apart...

**Comment by [Sparkle Eyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/38320/sparkle-eyes/) on 2019-05-30**:
As for the specific use-case, this is a demo program distributed in a docker environment, which I cannot build successfully on my laptop, so I decide to "go raw" and build the source myself....